# Create Opportunity related list on Product page layout

Tags: community, administration

I am trying to create Opportunity related list on Product page layout.
I searched and find out that this functionality is not available with point and click. Is someone help me with the coding part how to achieve this task? I new to salesforce and learning it by doing it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Related lists are displayed when they there's a relationship between the two objects.

As there's no direct relationship between the product and opportunity, try creating a visualforce page that queries all opportunity that contains that product in its opportunitylineitems then display accordingly. Then, have that page shown in the page layout of the product page.